# KNNImputer is replacing data with Nulls

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, missing-data, knn

I was working on a project with sensitive data and stumbled upon this "bug" (probably something that went over my head). Recently I learned about KNNimputer from sklearn and I love its concept. **However, it's replacing data with null values.** I'm working on a data cleaning and modeling project, at the moment I don't have any null data but I wanted to add code to fill nulls in the case there are in the future but after running the algorithm it's replacing good data with NaN values. Am I using it wrong?

#### Here is the code:

The libraries I use

```
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Transformed categorical data as dummies

```
df_cleaned = pd.get_dummies(df_cleaned, columns=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
    print("Categorical -> dummies \n", df_cleaned.info(5))
```

"I replaced the names of the features" 
"And didn't show the 33 columns as the remaining columns have 28519 non-null  uint8"

```
Data columns (total 33 columns):
 #   Column                   Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------                   --------------  ----- 
 0   A                        28519 non-null  int64 
 1   B                        28519 non-null  int64 
 2   C                        28519 non-null  object
 3   D                        28519 non-null  int64 
 4   E                        28519 non-null  int64 
 5   F                        28519 non-null  object
 6   H                        28519 non-null  int64 
 7   I                        28519 non-null  object
 8   J                        28519 non-null  uint8 
 9   K                        28519 non-null  uint8
```

```
print("looking for nulls (before) \n", df.isnull().sum())
```

There are no nulls at this moment

> looking for nulls (before) 
> A 0 
> B 0 
> C 0 
> D 0 
> E 0 
> F 0 
> G 0 
> H 0 
> I 0 
> J 0

**Something Happens here**

```
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)
df_immputed = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(df_cleaned.drop("venue", axis=1)), columns=df_cleaned.drop("venue", axis=1).columns)
df_cleaned = pd.concat([df_immputed, df_cleaned["venue"]], axis=1)
```

```
print("looking for nulls (after) \n", df.isnull().sum())
```

**Now there are**

> looking for nulls (after) 
> A 28 
> B 28 
> C 28 
> D 28 
> E 28 
> F 28 
> G 28 
> H 28 
> I 28 
> J 28

What is happening? Why is it creating nulls?

Edit:

**Row affected**
*The Letter_# are dummies*

Original row

```
A   B   C           D   E   F           G   H_1 H_2 H_3 H_4 H_5 H_6         
151 128 134110.51   681 532 593894.54   151 0   0   1   0   0   0

H_7 H_8 H_9 H_10    H_11    H_12    I_0 I_1 I_2 J_1 J_2 J_3 J_4 J_5         
0   0   0   0       0       0       0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   
        
J_6 K_1 K_1 L_1 L_2 M
0   0   1   1   0   string value I cannot share sorry
```

Row with nulls after Knnimputer

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H_1 H_2 H_3 H_4 H_5 H_6 H_7 H_8 H_9 H_10    
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

H_11    H_12    I_0 I_1 I_2 J_1 J_2 J_3 J_4 J_5 J_6 K_1 K_1 L_1 L_2 
NaN     NaN     NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

M
string value I cannot share sorry
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a sample dataset? Is it the same 28 rows with missing values for each feature? If so, can you provide those rows (or notice anything odd about them)?

Comment: I'm confused. You dropped `venue` from `df_cleaned` and after that concatenated dropped columns with KNN imputation ? What is the result of `df_immputed.isnull().sum()` ?

Comment: Yes, already updated the question with a row example :). I don't notice anything odd. However, I find it strange that it replaces the whole row with NaNs rather than only one value. I don't know if I'm using the algorithm wrong :(, I think I'm not.

Comment: @razimbres, later in the code I want to partition the data frame with this column (categorical) to create a model for each value. I have the hypothesis that the outcome of the predicted value changes with this value as it is somewhat of geographical value. However, I don't want to make it a dummy and knnimputer doesn't allow me to select which columns to affect, I just dropped it and added it after the "null filling strategy".

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to a nonstandard index of your dataframe. Check the shape of the output: if I'm right, you'll have 28 more rows than before.

The problem arises because when you re-dataframe the numpy result of `fit_transform`, you get a standard index (0...n-1). Then `pd.concat` matches those indices against the original index in the column `"venue"`, taking an outer join.

You can fix this in a number of ways; maybe the nicest is to assign the correct frame index when re-framing the imputed numpy array:

```py
df_immputed = pd.DataFrame(
    imputer.fit_transform(df_cleaned.drop("venue", axis=1)),
    columns=df_cleaned.drop("venue", axis=1).columns,
    index=df_cleaned.index,
)
```